# Looking for solution for Groovy @Mixin not to break encapsulation

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree, mixins

I want to use the @Mixin annotation in Groovy which does exactly what I want except for it also mixes in private methods and fields.

```
class A {
def private fooA() {
        println("A")
    }
}

@Mixin(A)
class B {
    def fooB() {
        println("B")
   }
}
```

If I now run this code

```
static main(args)
{
    def b = new B()
    println(b.fooA())
    B.metaClass.fooA = {throw new MissingMethodException()};
    println(b.fooA())
}
```

It first calls the private method A.fooA and prints "A". Then that private method is removed and cannot be called by the client class B of the mixed in class A. This is the way I would like things to be from the beginning.

My question is now how I can achieve this in a generic way? I can extend the @Mixin annotation. Problem is I'm new to Groovy and there is really not much information to find about how to write AST transformations. The new Groovy in Action book that has a whole chapter about it is not out yet.

I can use @Delegate instead, but then I have to declare a variable for the class delegated to. This is not what I want. I would prefer that I can just tell the developer using my stuff simply to annotate his class with @Mixin in order to mix in my stuff and that's it. And I can be sure the private methods and fields of my class cannot be called by the user breaking internal code of the class mixed in.

Does anyone have a hint in what direction I should try to get this done?
Thanks, Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've hit on something that is not a strong focus of Groovy.  Support for hiding private members has [issues](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3010) in general.

In your specific case, you may have happened on a new bug(?).  Poking around, it looks like the AST transform for `@Mixin` invokes code that reaches `MixinInMetaClass.mixinClassesToMetaClass()`.  This is making an effort not to copy over non-public methods to the target metaclass (that of your class B); they don't show up in the list of methods on your `b.metaClass`, so that seems correct.

Calls to `b.fooA()` will work (somehow) until you try to use a non-existant property or call a non-existant method on b.  (or call `b.metaClass.initialize()`).  Then you will get complaints the missing `fooA()`.

So, I'm not sure I'd put too much energy into trying to get access modifiers to work with Groovy, but if you keep down that path, I think you may have to write some initialization code for classes to do something like you've done above, or call `initialize()` or a bad property as I've noted above.  You could attempt to put some of this code in your own `ASTTransformation` class, but I've not tried that.  You could grab the [source](http://dist.groovy.codehaus.org/distributions/groovy-src-2.0.5.zip) and have a look at `org.codehaus.groovy.ast.MixinASTTransformation`.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer. Well, when the auto-completion selection list pops up in the IDE (I use IDEA) after typing in "f." the private method fooA is not listed as a selectable option (but fooB is). Any developer still invoking fooA on an instance of B has been sort of warned before. Maybe that's good enough. Eventually, I'm too much used to my previous "everything type safe" world ;-).